# Qt 5 - как запретить приложению использовать другие экраны?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, directx, экран

Приветствую.
Есть приложение на Qt 5 с использованием DirectX 11. У него сейчас есть один вьюпорт, должно быть четыре. При старте приложение разворачивается на весь экран и регистрирует размеры окон(создаёт поверхности рисования). Есть сложности с изменением размеров вьюпортов, поэтому они все жестко фиксированы - четыре вьюпорта с равными размерами или один, размеры менять нельзя. Ради этого приложение развёрнуто на весь экран и убрана возможность его сворачивать в окно. Посчитал, что обычного экрана на 22-24 дюйма пользователю хватит(а есть экраны и больше). Предположим, у пользователя, как у меня, ноутбук и внешний экран. Тогда он может перетащить окно на другой экран, последствия будут печальные - приложение свернётся в окно(несмотря на то, что я это запрещал), развернуть его обратно пользователь не сможет(я запретил), а у меня с разворотом будут сложности - эти два рабочих стола могут быть на разных видеокартах, соответственно, что там будет с ресурсами, непонятно, и вернуть нельзя. Использование других экранов нужно временно запретить. Как это сделать? Проверил такой способ:

```
void Vesta::RevertMyScreen(QScreen *screen)
{
windowHandle()->setScreen(MyScreen);
windowHandle()->showFullScreen();
}
```

и получилось еще хуже: окно переходит в неправильное состояние, из которого можно выбраться только перезапуском...

Comment: Кажется, нашёл решение. Нужно сделать так:   `setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
 setWindowFlags(Qt::Window |  Qt::FramelessWindowHint);`. После этого пропадёт полоса заголовка с именем приложения, значком и кнопками управления. Таскать на другие экраны станет нельзя - то, что нужно. Единственный затык - нельзя сворачивать в панель задач, но с этим я потом разберусь.

Comment: Зачем такие сложности? лично меня бесят программы, которые нельзя перетащить, или у которых что-то задано слишком жёстко. На вашем месте я бы не парился, хотя всё зависит от ТЗ.